# Exposing node Server running on docker doesn't work

Tags: node.js, docker, publish

I am running a angular app on node server and in server.js I have specified `app.listen(8084,localhost)`..So when i run npm start in the docker container and try to `-p 8084:8084` in docker run I was not able to get anything, even though the curl command inside my container `curl localhost:8084` was giving me right result.
So i change the `app.listen(8084)` and the `-p 8084:8084` started working..I am not sure why ?

Answer (score 2):

When you open socket, you need to bind it to some interface in your system. There are predefined values:

`0.0.0.0` - all interfaces, your service will be available from any interface

`locahost`, `127.0.0.1` - bind **locally**. That means service is NOT available from oustide -- this is your case.

You also can specify particular interface IP address to bind to it.

When you start your container, by default docker start `default bridge network`, so your container is being put into separate network and to access it, you need to allow incoming remote connections in container.

Answer (score 0):

You bind your service to localhost into a container, so no communication is possible outside the container. localhost for your node server is not the same than localhost for your container.